# SVG drawables do not show up on some Android 9 devices

Tags: android, xml, svg, icons, drawable

In my Android app, I recently migrated from using PNG icons to SVG drawables. This worked well in the Android emulator and works fine on most of our users devices, however, especially Asus phone owners with Android 9 report they don't see the icons (however they can still be clicked on).

Example icon (menu_navigation.xml)

```
<vector android:height="24dp" android:viewportHeight="16"
    android:viewportWidth="16" android:width="24dp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <path android:fillAlpha="0" android:fillColor="#D8D8D8"
        android:fillType="evenOdd" android:pathData="M-3,0h19v19h-19z"
        android:strokeAlpha="0" android:strokeColor="#00000000" android:strokeWidth="1"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#00000000" android:fillType="evenOdd"
        android:pathData="M12,11.3333C12,12.0083 11.4528,12.5556 10.7778,12.5556L3.4444,12.5556L1,15L1,5.2222C1,4.5472 1.5472,4 2.2222,4L10.7778,4C11.4528,4 12,4.5472 12,5.2222L12,11.3333Z"
        android:strokeColor="#FFFFFF" android:strokeLineCap="round"
        android:strokeLineJoin="round" android:strokeWidth="1.5"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#F8E71C" android:fillType="evenOdd"
        android:pathData="M14.5,1.5m-1.5,0a1.5,1.5 0,1 1,3 0a1.5,1.5 0,1 1,-3 0"
        android:strokeColor="#00000000" android:strokeWidth="1"/>
</vector>
```

Use in BottomNavigationMenu:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
...
 <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_conversations"
        android:icon="@drawable/menu_conversations"
        android:checkable="true"
        android:checked="true"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="" />
...
</menu>
```

In Activity:

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navigation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_3"
            app:itemBackground="@drawable/menu_selector"
            app:itemIconTint="@android:color/white"
            app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:menu="@menu/navigation" />
```

How the icon should be shown:
[image: How the icon should be shown]
<sub>(source: [kvetinac97.cz](https://www.kvetinac97.cz/uploads/correct.png))</sub>

What the user sees:
[image: What the user sees]
<sub>(source: [kvetinac97.cz](https://www.kvetinac97.cz/uploads/wrong.png))</sub>

(Please ignore that order of 2nd and 3rd icon is reversed)

Any idea what could be causing the icon to disappear? Other icons (pngs) show normally.